# If no funciona correctamente - PHP

Tags: php, html

¿Por qué el segundo `if` no funciona?
Al hacer `echo` y comentar ese `if` el resultado del mismo es 1 (en el caso en el que estoy) y si es 1 o 2 no debería redireccionarme pero si que lo hace, ¿alguien ve el fallo?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("db_files/db.php");
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ header("Location: index.php"); }
    echo $_SESSION['userlevel'];
    if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] != 1 || $_SESSION['userlevel'] != 2) { header ("location: mainindex.php");}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es que si es 1 **o** 2... te da uno **o** el otro `true` y te redirecciona.

Lo puedes solucionar de esta manera más simple:

```
if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] > 2) {

  header ("location: mainindex.php");
}
```

o con tu código lo comparas con el operado `&&`:

```
if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] != 1 && $_SESSION['userlevel'] != 2) {

  header ("location: mainindex.php");
}
```

Comment: Como adición a esta respuesta que está muy correcta: Se puede cambiar también el `||` (OR) por `&&` (AND).

Comment: @Error404 - Si lo se estaba en ello de ponerlo también como otra opción pero la primera es mas corta y limpia... Gracias de todas manera!

Comment: De nada :) Si, por eso no lo puse como respuesta, porque ví que la tuya lo completaba mucho mejor y es mucho más limpia. Realmente era simplemente para que el OP viera que su fallo había sido poner OR en vez de AND.